# How to locate an NoSuchMethodError

Tags: flutter, dart

I guess just like everyone I am facing a `NoSuchMethodError` every now and then. Usually when calling some method on an uninitialized List or something else.

I normally find that error pretty quickly. But I am wondering if there is a method to get the debugger halted on that specific line?

Even better would it be if flutter would additionally print the line number and file into the console and not just that this error has occured. Am I missing any verbosity setting in the console or is that simply not possible?

Thanks!

(Btw. this is not about solving the error from the screenshot. This is about this error in general)

[image]